# image hover style not able to implement

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to bootstrap and have tried implementing background color change on hover.
Well, it's happening, but not perfectly. It needs to be implemented in this way.

There is this full height hover effect after the carousel container.

I have tried with padding and min height, still not able to achieve.

[image]

My code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cnetric | Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="navbar-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 offset-sm-5">
                    <ul class="list-inline">
                        <li class="list-inline-item">Agile</li>
                        <li class="list-inline-item">Open Source</li>
                        <li class="list-inline-item">Digitalization</li>
                        <li class="list-inline-item">Enterprise</li>
                        <li class="list-inline-item">Knowledge Base</li>
                        <li class="list-inline-item">english</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="./images/Cnetric_High-Res_Logo.png" width="160px" height="65px"
                        alt="Cnetric Company Logo"></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Capabilities</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Solutions</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Our Team</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Our Clients</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ul class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ul>

        <!-- The slideshow -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="./images/new-york-city-3.jpg" alt="New York">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-block h-50 text-left">
                    <h1>LEADERS IN</h1>
                    <h2>DIGITAL TRANSFORMATION</h2>
                    <p>Delivering and supporting business-critical commerce solutions that power your growth</p>
                    <button class="btn btn-warning">Read More</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="./images/new-york-city-3.jpg" alt="Chicago">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="./images/new-york-city-3.jpg" alt="New York">
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
        </a>

    </div>
    <div class="container application-container">
        <div class="row mb-5">
            <div class="col-lg-2 text-center image-container">
                <img src="./images/aoe_icons_services_order_management.svg" width="60" height="67" alt="New York">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 text-center image-container">
                <img src="./images/aoe_icons_webportal.svg" width="60" height="67" alt="New York">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 text-center image-container">
                <img src="./images/aoe_icons_technologies-13.svg" width="60" height="67" alt="New York">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 text-center image-container">
                <img src="./images/aoe_icons_web_and_mobile_applications.svg" width="60" height="67" alt="New York">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 text-center image-container">
                <img src="./images/aoe_icons_web_content_management.svg" width="60" height="67" alt="New York">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1 text-center image-container">
                <img src="./images/Search2.svg" width="60" height="67" alt="New York">
            </div>
            <div class="col text-center mt-3">
                <p>View All</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Styles.css

```
.application-container .image-container:hover{
    background-color: #EFF3F6;
  }

  .application-container .image-container {
    position: relative;
  }

  .application-container .image-container:hover:after {
   content: "";
   display: block;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #EFF3F6;
   position: absolute;
   left: 45%;
   bottom: 66px;
  }
```

After implementing the above code all I get is like this.
The hover effect should be between carousel and the application container
I tried using line-height property,but it's not working.
Can somebody please help/ guide me on this.

[image]

Comment: all you need to do is set the min height for your image-container class...

Comment: @MasihAnsari it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Adding `display: inline-block; padding: 20px;` in `.application-container .image-container` will do your work,

Hope this helps

Comment: check this fiddle, i have used the same as i said and it seems to work
https://jsfiddle.net/6uedrb89/10/

Comment: I have edited my question....Can you check it a bit.....The hover effect is between carousel container and application container

Answer (score 0):

Add class `.py-*` (i.e `py-1`) to the `.image-container` to add spacing.

Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/#notation

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, changed style and get the below output:

[image]

for this change, kindly update the below style:

```
.application-container .image-container {
     position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
  } 

  .application-container .image-container:hover:after {
   content: "";
   display: block;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #EFF3F6;
   position: absolute;
   left: 45%;
       top: -10px;
  }
```

Comment: The hover effect is between the carousel and application container.....I have edited my question....It's not taking the full height.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work for you: https://jsfiddle.net/abhineetV/gf4qhswc/26/
I have changed some structure.

```
<div class="container application-container">
  <ul class="banner-nav list-unstyled d-flex justify-content-center">
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="d-flex flex-column"><span class="oi oi-account-login"></span><div>
      account login
      </div></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="d-flex flex-column"><span class="oi oi-pencil"></span><div>
      pencil
      </div></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="d-flex flex-column"><span class="oi oi-shield"></span><div>
      shield
      </div></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="d-flex flex-column"><span class="oi oi-arrow-right"></span> <div>
     View All
     </div></a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.banner-nav>li {
  width: 120px;
}

.banner-nav>li>a {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.banner-nav>li>a:hover {
  background-color: #EFF3F6;
}
```